# How to access Default en-US culture, not as defined on a specific system?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to make my application handle some conversions of DateTimes from string.  In order to handle varying culture, I specify the culture I want the conversion to use.  I thought that had me covered, but I discovered that you can change specific elements of how that system defines "en-US", like the long and short date patterns.
In those cases, the code below does not work, when the dates being parsed are in MM/dd/yyyy format.

```
        CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        string[] permissions = Regex.Split(permissionData, @"\r\n");
        foreach (string permission in permissions)
        {
            string[] details = permission.Split(',');
            this.Add(new WPermission()
            {
                WRegion = Convert.ToInt32(details[0],c),
                StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(details[1],c),
                EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(details[2],c)
            });
        }
```

My question is: Is there a way to access the default definition of "en-US", and load that instead of the user defined version, or am I relegated to something like `ParseExact`? As a note, I cannot control the source format of the string I am parsing, it's third party.

Thanks!

Comment: Did ParseExact work for you?  It's so weird that the code above doesn't work...

Comment: I ended up using `InvariantCulture` as suggested in the answers.  The problem is that the machine specific implementation of "en-US" can be customized, so it's not a valid constant to use as a basis for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx), which is associated with English, but ignores regional information and user customizations.

```
this.Add(new WPermission() {
    WRegion = Convert.ToInt32(details[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(details[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(details[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This specific example could be handled by [using the Invariant Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a.aspx), which uses US style date formatting.

However, you may want to still use `DateTime.ParseExact` if you know the exact representation of the dates, as it also has the additional side effect of showing the intent to parse the date in that *exact format* very clear.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, the only reason I gave the answer to the other poster was he beat you by a few seconds.  Good note of the reason to use ParseExact as well.

Answer (score 0):

InvariantCulture works great for English, but for a more generic solution that works with other languages, try:

`CultureInfo c = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);`

Adding false to the constructor tells it to disregard any user customizations for the culture.